# pandas creating new column and adding it to sql database

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to convert all the time stamps in my database from unixtime to a formatted, human-readable time. Once formatted, it should then create a new column with the name `formatted_date` and then write that column back to the SQL database I am connected to.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from patsy import dmatrices
import sqlite3
import datetime

con = sqlite3.connect('file_name')

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table', con, chunksize=1000)

def format_date(x):
    format_date = x.unixtime = pd.to_datetime(x.unixtime, unit='s')
    return format_date

for x in df:
    x['formatted_date'] = x.apply(format_date(x)).tosql('bitcoin', con,     if_exists='append')

con.close()
```

The code correctly converts to the right format, but breaks down during the `for x in df` loop where I try to create the new column and add it to the db. The error I get is:

> TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index unixtime')

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to pull the data into pandas in order to convert unix time to timestamp, as [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) seems to support datestring conversions:

```
Compute the date and time given a unix timestamp 1092941466, and compensate for your local timezone.

SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

But if you still have to, you can convert unix timestamps to date strings like this:

```
import datetime

unix_ts = 1546732800.0
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_ts)
datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')

'2019-01-05'
```